# How can i keep chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText for each tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension gets data using tab.url and puts it in chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText. When i open a new tab it resets. How can i update BadgeText only for a new tab? and keep it unchanged for an old one?

extension layout:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    //using tab.url and XMLHttpRequest() i get newText for:
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: newText});
   };
});
```

Comment: We need relevant code to help.

Comment: Would a page action be more appropriate?  What does it do?

Comment: it shows statistics of a current domain

Comment: So explain how do you want the badge to behave. Should it only be computed once on navigation? Should it change when you switch tabs?

Comment: Yes, it should change when switch tabs or when you change url of a current tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two key points should help you with your troubles.

1) [`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) has an optional parameter, `tabId`, that binds the value to the tab.

2) You should filter `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` events by [`changeInfo`'s fields](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

So, change your code to:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
        if(!changeInfo.url) return; // URL did not change
        // Might be better to analyze the URL to exclude things like anchor changes

        /* ... */
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: newText, tabId: tab.id});
    };
});
```

This might not catch new tabs' creation; if it doesn't, also listen to `onCreated`

Comment: Thank you Xan! the key is a tab.id: chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: newText, tabId: tab.id});

Answer (score 3):

```
 chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: newText}, tab.id);  //<<this is not working to me

 chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "Phish", tabId: tab.id}); //<<This is working to me
```